# mysql select statement result limit

Tags: mysql, select, nested, limit

I have query:

```
select id, name from categories where parent_id in (
    select id 
    from categories 
    where top_main_place > 0
)
```

it selects child info (outer select) of their parent nodes (inner select)

the problem is: I don't need to have all child nodes data, maximum **6** child nodes data per parent `id`

how can I reach this result?

*btw, sorry for my poor english*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should order the outer query by parent_id, give each row a row number (resetting the row number whenever parent_id changes) and then filter out any row with row number greater than 6, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619117/sorting-groups-of-data-looking-at-the-newest-entry/7619279#7619279) for example and sql code.

Answer (score 0):

This page shows how to limit the number of results returned by a query, in several dialects of SQL:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name FROM (
    select id, name, IF(@parent_id=parent_id, @count:=@count+1, @count:=0) as count, @parent_id:=parent_id from categories, (select @count:=0, @parent_id:=0) as x where parent_id in (
        select id 
        from categories 
        where top_main_place > 0
    ) order by parent_id
) y where count <= 6;
```

Comment: Looks like @nobody beat me to the suggestion, but this should work.